# matlab deploy application paths and other dependencies

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I have a matlab code which contains several .m files in sub folders. When I call the matlab I am using the following function.

```
addpath(genpath('myfolder'));
```

My code uses some other libraries such as `liblinear`.

My question is how can I create a matlab executables from my code. 
How should I add the subfolders and 'addpath'?
How can I include my `liblinear` functions there (from `liblinear` library/code)?

Comment: You want to create executables and then use them? Or do you want to use the functions that are defined in files like "liblinear/function1.m"? You understand executables and functions are not the same, right?

Comment: Ya. I have a function call 'mainTask' that includes some other functions from liblinear. I want to create an executable which should be able to run on other machines. I should be able to call that exe from command line passing some arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab compiler crawls through your files and figures out the dependencies by himself.
Thus, in most case you don't need to do anything. It will add `mex` files as well (which are in the path), such as `liblinear.mex`.

However, in some cases the compiler cannot figure out what functions to add to the compiled archive.

- If you are calling a function using `eval`.
- If you are inheritance of objects, you need to add father class(compiler bug)

You need to help him by adding pragma in your `.m` files:

```
%#function MyFunc1
...
 eval('MyFunc1');
...
```

Or adding the files in the [compilation command](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2010/11/18/deploying-standalone-applications/):

```
mcc .... -a MyFunc1.m
```

Comment: One thing I would like to add to this answer is that if you are adding path in your m-files, like "addpath(genpath('myfolder'));", you need to remove or comment it when creating the executable.

Comment: More info - https://admin.kuleuven.be/icts/onderzoek/wetsoft/software/matlab/pdf/matlab-deploytool-standalone